# Warum ist die Bezeichnung "Roter Weg" so häufig?

Tags: place-name

In Städten und Dörfern in Nordrhein-Westfalen und Baden-Württemberg habe ich oft Straßen oder Wege mit dem Namen *Roter Weg* gesehen. Wie kommt es, daß diese Bezeichnung so häufig ist, und es nicht auch manchmal *Grüner Weg* oder *Blauer Weg* heißt? Ich nehme einmal an, daß es nichts mit Kommunismus zu tun hat.

Comment: Würde auf roten Backstein tippen, oder dass es dort roten Lehm im Boden gab/gibt.

Comment: Es gibt auch viele mit Städte mit einer _Rote Straße_ oder _Rote Gasse_. Die Frage ist allerdings hier ebenfalls, ob Grüner Weg oder Blauer Weg wirklich im Vergleich so selten sind (oder der Eindruck der Verteilung einfach täuscht). Städte mit diesen farbigen Straßennamen gibt es nämlich durchaus.

Comment: z.B. roter Ziegelsteinschutt bildet den Untergrund für einen neuen Weg, der deshalb den Namen „Roter Weg” bekommt oder als Ableitung von der dort vorherrschenden geologischen Formation des [Rotliegend](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotliegend)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Roth, auch Rötel oder Rot kommt in erstaunlich vielen Flur- Gewässer- und Gemeindenamen überall im deutschen Sprachraum (nicht nur NRW und BW) vor.

*Rötel* ist eine Bezeichnung für eine mineralische Farbe mit einem roten Farbton auf Eisenoxydbasis, die schon die Neandertaler für ihre Höhlenmalereien verwendet haben - Da rote Farbe alternativ hauptsächlich aus Färberkrapp (einer Pflanze) gewonnen werden konnte und man in Europa erst im späten Mittelalter mit diesen pflanzenbasierten Farbstoffen verlässliche Rottöne erzeugen konnte, war der Rötel lange Zeit der einzige Lieferant für rote Farbe. Es lag daher nahe, Flurnamen so zu wählen, dass die Besonderheit "hier gibt es rote Farbe" darin zum Ausdruck kam.

Ein Bach oder Fluss der Rötel in seinem Lauf mitführte, hieß damit leicht "[Rothenbach](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rothenbach_(Begriffskl%C3%A4rung))", "[Roth](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth_(Donau))", ein Hohlweg mit Rötelaufschlüssen "Rotweg" oder "Roter Weg", und ein Berg, an dem eisenoxydhaltiges und damit rotes Gestein vorkam, "Rotenberg". (Ich habe aufgehört, Verweise zu suchen, es gibt einfach zu viele davon)

Für manche Flurnamen, die nicht eindeutig auf die Farbe "rot" zurückgeführt werden können, kommt eine andere Herkunft in Betracht, nämlich von dem Verb *roden* bzw. dem zugeordneten Nomen *[Rodung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodungsname)* - Eine Siedlung oder Ackerland, die dem Wald durch Rodung abgetrotzt worden waren, kann ebenfalls einen Namen tragen, der "rot" enthält. Viele Gemeindenamen im Harz wie "Gernrode", "Harzgerode", "Osterode" haben diese Herkunft noch sichtbarer als z.B. [Rotenburg/Wümme](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotenburg_(W%C3%BCmme)) (dort wird die Herkunft von "Rodung" auch für wahrscheinlich gehalten)

Deine Annahme, dass das "rot" nichts mit Kommunismus zu tun hat, ist natürlich richtig - Flurnamen sind normalerweise wesentlich älter als die Ideologie.

**Fun Fact:**
 Nicht einmal der Inbegriff eines Eigennamens, der mit "politisch rot" verbunden wird, der *[Rote Platz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roter_Platz)* in Moskau, hat etwas mit Kommunismus zu tun.

Comment: Und die Rote Zora?

Comment: @tofro Sehr interessant, danke! Eine Anmerkung zu dem fun fact: Auf Russisch ist die Bezeichung ja Красная площадь und красная bedeutet rot und aber auch schön. Man könnte also auch Schöner Platz übersetzen.